# How to set custom User-Agent with apache http client library 4.1?

Tags: java, user-agent, apache-httpclient-4.x

How to make HTTPClient use custom User-Agent header?

The following code submits empty user-agent. What am I missing?

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class TestHTTP {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://tool.keepmeapi.com/echo");

        HttpContext HTTP_CONTEXT = new BasicHttpContext();
        HTTP_CONTEXT.setAttribute(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13");
        request.setHeader("Referer", "http://www.google.com");

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request, HTTP_CONTEXT);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < 200 || response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() >= 400) {
            throw new IOException("Got bad response, error code = " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Note:** The solution is for users using the old httpcomponents 4.2 and before.

The line

`request.setHeader("User-Agent", "MySuperUserAgent");`

is missing. Add it and enjoy.

Comment: So simple... :) I wonder what the CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT is for then?

Comment: I do not know. I do not have this class, but probably it is just a constant "User-Agent"?

Comment: @AlexR : CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT should be used with org.apache.http.params.HttpParams to configure your httpClient which is in your case DefaultHttpClient. So you could pass user agent as second parameter of constructor of DefaultHttpClient or via serDefaultHttpParams.

Comment: For those using httpcomponents 4.3 and up, scroll down to the @MrSpock answer. You can set user-agent on HttpClient.

Answer (score 49):

**Note:** Starting from httpcomponents 4.3 this solution is **deprecated**.

You can also set a global user agent value instead of per request:

```
String userAgent = "NewUseAgent/1.0";
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, userAgent);
```

Comment: I used the `HTTP.USER_AGENT` as the parameter name. Although not sure which is preferred.

Comment: `CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT` is the only one that will work. HTTP.USER_AGENT is just the name of the http header itself, not the name of the property that we're sending to httpclient.

Comment: Apache's doc says CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT is deprecated. What should be used instead? http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-dev/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/CoreProtocolPNames.html

Comment: You should use HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent

Comment: I tried changing params in different versions of apache libary, but it never worked.

Better is using 'yourrequest.addHeader("User-Agent","YourApp/x.x")'

Comment: You could use HttpMethodParams.USER_AGENT constant instead of the deprecated one.

Answer (score 38):

With httpcomponents 4.3 you should use the client builder to set the user agent:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                            .setUserAgent("my UserAgent 5.0")
                            .build();

httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("http://www.google.de"));
```