# Exec'ing CURL from Java - whats the proper way?

Tags: java, shell, curl, exec

I am executing curl via the following code:

```
  // execute process
    Process pr = null;
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        pr = run.exec(cmdline.split(" "));

        A ret = f.f(pr);

        pr.waitFor();

        return ret;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Executing " + cmdline, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            // close all those bloody streams
            pr.getErrorStream().close();
            pr.getInputStream().close();
            pr.getOutputStream().close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.get().exception(Log.Level.Error, "Closing stream: ", ex);
        }
    }
```

However, when I add the following into the exec string:

I am building the curl string as I go, before I pass it to the method seen above:

```
        if (userAgent.contains(" ")) {
            userAgent = " --user-agent '" + Exec.escapeShellString(userAgent) + "' ";
        }
```

With the extra single quotes I get this:

```
113.30.31.137 - - [03/Feb/2012:05:26:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6781 "-" "'Mozilla/5.0(iPad;U;CPUOS3_2_1)'"
```

Without the single quotes, I get this:

```
107.21.172.36 - - [03/Feb/2012:05:33:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6781 "-" "'Mozilla/5.0(iPad;U;CPUOS3_2_1)"
```

There is a leading single quote, but not a finishing one.  I believe that there should be no single quotes..  anyhow, there is magic somewhere between java and curl...

All I would like to do is pass a string like this:
    Opera/9.25 (Windows NT 6.0; U; en)

and expect this:

```
107.21.172.36 - - [03/Feb/2012:05:33:38 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6781 "-" "Opera/9.25 (Windows NT 6.0; U; en)"
```

Edit:

The reason I am using curl is because curl seems to be the only option that retrieves the content on any response other than 200.301 or 302.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are trying to use curl from java when you have a library called [Apache httpcleint](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) to handle these things in java.

Take a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027309/how-to-set-custom-user-agent-with-apache-http-client-library-4-1).

Alternatively you can also use java's inbuilt [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) or [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class for these purposes.

If you are from a PHP background and if you **insist** on using cURL try [libcurl Java bindings](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/java/).

Comment: The reason I am using curl is because curl seems to be the only option that retrieves the content on any response other than 200.301 or 302.

Answer (score 1):

You could use HttpClient from apache to send all the necessary headers you want:

```
 import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
 import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod; 



 public static void main(String[] args) throws HttpException, IOException { 

     HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
     GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod("http://cetatenie.just.ro/Home/ORDINEANC.aspx");
     getMethod.addRequestHeader("Host", "cetatenie.just.ro");
     getMethod.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1");

     httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
     String response = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString(); 
   }
}
```

This is just one small example.