# How does server distinguish HTTP requests sent from what kind of http client?

Tags: spring, apache, browser, httpclient

I have a spring server. is that a way to know what kind of client was used to send the request received on my server? I want to distinguish whether it's from browsers (ie, ff, chrome, safari) or from other application, e.g Apache http client or any other http client libraries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That information is in the User-Agent header.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This may work but as UserAgent can be modified if the client trying to cheat the server. The reason I am asking was I wanted to distinguish the requests are from regular browsers or robots.

Comment: You can't. The entire request is completely under the control of the user agent.

Comment: it may not be true. see this [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-http-request-heade/ppmibgfeefcglejjlpeihfdimbkfbbnm?hl=en), and this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027309/how-to-set-custom-user-agent-with-apache-http-client-library-4-1).