# Scraping cricinfo only two pages are being loaded

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, apache-httpcomponents

I am scraping [espncricinfo](http://www.espncricinfo.com/).

Goal is to extract batting statistics for each player of specified country. Right now I am extracting all players in **Input Country** and then for each player I am parsing another link that will give me batting stats of that player.

I am using **Apache HttpComponents** for http requests and **JSoup** for parsing DOM elements.

Everything is going perfect but the only problem I am facing is when I start scraping two players are being scraped perfectly and then my application hangs.

I've narrowed the problem to a method which grabs a single page, If I provide any link of espncricinfo to this method it is only able to process two requests and no more.

I imagine the problem might be some kind of bot prevention mechanism implemented by espncricinfo. Can anybody help how to bypass this?

Here is code of grab method

```
public Document scrapSinglePage(String method, String url) {
        try {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            String htmlResponse = "";

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet, getLocalContext());
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                htmlResponse += "\r\n" + line;
            }

            //Parse response
            document = Jsoup.parse(htmlResponse);
            return document;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Scrapper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I will appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Does it always hang on a specific URL ? If so, post the URL it hangs on.

Comment: Nope for any URL, just two requests are made and they no response at all...

Comment: You mean that two requests work, but the third one always fails ? Try using the Java built in network classes, eg. HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: You might be right about the bot prevention. You can solve this by providing a userAgent when making the http call. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027309/how-to-set-custom-user-agent-with-apache-http-client-library-4-1

Comment: thanks guys for your comments i solved it by destroying current session completely... So for each request i get a new cookie from espncricinfo and they can't track my requests... I am not 100% percent sure if its bot prevention but this is how it works in normal way it ain't working...