# Apache HttpClientBuilder.create().setUserAgent(...) not working

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

Here is how I am creating HttpClient :

```java
private String userAgent= "Non empty user agent";
private HttpClient httpClient= HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .setDefaultCookieStore(new BasicCookieStore())
    .setUserAgent(userAgent)
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
        .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
        .build())
    .setDefaultHeaders(Arrays.asList(
        new BasicHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"),
        new BasicHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")))
    .build();
```

But when sending some request, the USER AGENT is **empty**, here is the log :

```
12:51:33.807 [http-nio-5010-exec-9] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> GET / HTTP/1.1
12:51:33.807 [http-nio-5010-exec-9] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept- Encoding: gzip
12:51:33.807 [http-nio-5010-exec-9] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: www.somehost.com
12:51:33.807 [http-nio-5010-exec-9] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: keep-alive
12:51:33.807 [http-nio-5010-exec-9] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent:
```

I tried to set the user Agent as default header like this :

```java
.setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
    .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build())
.setDefaultHeaders(Arrays.asList(
    new BasicHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"),
    new BasicHeader("Connection", "keep-alive"),
    new BasicHeader("User-Agent", userAgent)))
.build();
```

but same result (user agent is empty).

Here is how I am sending request :

```java
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(baseUrl));
```

maven pom dependency for Http Client :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you try to set the header normally with `.setHeader("User-Agent", userAgent)` instead of `.setDefaultHeaders()` just like described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5027588/3329810 ?

Comment: I didn't, if I use .setHeader I have to do it for each request I perform, it is risky, I can forget to do ir for some request, .setDefaultHeaders on httpClientBuilder is meant to call .setHeader for each request performed using the httpClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in instantiation order : in fact I am using SpringBoot, and the user agent value is loaded from properties file, here is it :

```
 @Value("${com.myapplication.userAgent}")
 private String userAgent;
private HttpClient httpClient= HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .setDefaultCookieStore(new BasicCookieStore())
    .setUserAgent(userAgent)
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build())
    .setDefaultHeaders(Arrays.asList(
            new BasicHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"),
            new BasicHeader("Connection", "keep-alive"))
    )
    .build();
```

The JVM instantiates httpClient before value injection occurs for userAgent, so when instantiating httpClient the userAgent value is null.

Thanks for your mental effort,